# Существуют ли минусы в разных используемых IDE в команде?

Tags: java

На данный момент работаю программистом `python`. У нас абсолютно не важно какая `IDE` у каждого члена команды. Просматривая вакансии `java`-разработчиков вижу, что часто указывается `IDE` для работы в команде. Не понимаю, на что это влияет ?

Comment: На преднастроенные утилиты/конфиги, следящие за кодстайлом/качеством кода.

Comment: @vp_arth а эти конфиги или их налоги не имеются в других `IDE` ?

Comment: Аналоги есть, но когда ide одна - их можно прям в репу добавить. Зоопарк в репу лучше не добавлять

Comment: @vp_arth то есть, тех кто использует другую `IDE` бьют по рукам или есть какой-то выход ?

Comment: Выход есть - искать разработчиков, к которым IDE гвоздями не прибита. Либо использовать другие средства контроля качества кода, статические анализаторы на хуках `pre-receive`, например.